# htaccess redirect php to html with https

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have problem with htacces rewrite rule with activated SSL.

In htacces I have all adress `.php` redirected to `.html`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

If I add ssl redirect to https via:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Rewrite php to html not working.

For example:

> http:// domain.com/test.html --- WORK
>
> http:// domain.com/test.php  --> REDIRECTED TO HTML AND WORK
>
> https:// domain.com/test.php --> NOT REDIRECTED -- WORK
>
> https:// domain.com/test.html --> ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND

**SOLVED**
It was problem in apache2 configuration for https site:

change *AllowOverride None* to *AllowOverride All*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for you help.. Problem solved -> Solution in original topik

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for you help.. Problem solved -> Solution in original topik